# Magnification - When is it negative?

Tags: visible-light, waves, lenses

In magnification, I keep on confusing the signs.
From what I understand currently, magnification is positive when the image is erect. An image is only erect when it is a virtual image, therefore virtual images = positive magnification. Vice versa, magnification is negative when the image is inverted, therefore a real image.

However using the equation $m = v/u$, $m$ is negative when $v$ is negative. And $v$ is only negative when the image is on the same side of the lens as the object. Therefore meaning a virtual image (According to physicsclassroom "The negative value for image distance indicates that the image is a virtual image located on the object's side of the lens."). This contradicts the statement above where virtual images = positive magnification.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you assuming a single lens? If you use multiple lenses you can have erect real images (2 positive lenses in a row, properly spaced will double-invert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is wrong. It there should be a -ve sign in it :

$$m=\frac{h_i}{h_o}=-\frac{v}{u}$$

See http://www.physicsclassroom.com/calcpad/refln under "Curved Mirror Mathematics". The text explains :

> The negative sign in the above equation is related to what could be the most problematic aspect of this set of problems. The variables in these two equations can be either positive or negative. The positive and negative nature is determined by the actual characteristics of the images which are formed and the mirrors which are used in the specific problems.

It goes on to provide a table summarizing the sign conventions.

Comment: Yes, sign conventions are absolutely essential.  There are systems which have negative signs for image distances of real images.  Not commonly taught in introductory physics, but used extensively in advanced geometrical optics because it adapts more easily to computer algorithms in optics design.

Answer (score 0):

In optics, the following concepts should be kept distinct in your thinking:

1. where an object or image is located (e.g. on one side or another of a lens or mirror)
2. whether an image is real or virtual
3. whether an image is erect or inverted

In general all combinations of the above are possible when there are multiple lenses.You can have a real image before one lens combination, and after another lens combination. You can have a real image which is erect for one lens combination, and inverted for another, etc.

For a single lens, (idealized), the quantities $u$ (object distance) and $v$ (image distance) and $f$ (focal length), related by
$$
\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{f},
$$
are all signed quantities. That is, they can each be positive or negative.

The standard convention on these signs, for a lens, is:

1. $f$ is positive for a converging lens (e.g. a convex-convex one), and negative for a diverging lens (e.g. a concave-concave one).
2. if light is travelling left to right then $u$ is positive when the object is before, i.e. to left of, lens
3. $v$ is positive when the image is after lens, (i.e. to right of lens if
   the light is travelling left to right)

For example, when an object is placed at distance $2f$ in front of a converging lens then we get a real inverted image at distance $2f$ after the lens. This situation is described by $f > 0$, $u = 2f$, $v=2f$ and the magnification is $M = -1$. More generally the magnification for a single lens, with $u$ and $v$ as described above, is given by
$$
M = - \frac{v}{u} .
$$
The best way to be confident of the sign in this formula is to draw the ray diagram for the case $u=v=2f$ and it is plain as day that the image is real and inverted.

When we use a magnifying glass, for example to magnify text on a page, we hold the lens a little closer to the paper than $f$, so this case is described by $u < f$. But since
$$
\frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{f} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{u - f}{uf}
$$
we shall then find that $v$ is negative. This means the image is on the same side of the lens as the object, and now we will find that $M$ is positive. The formula
$$
M = - \frac{v}{u} \;\;\;\; > 0  \; \mbox{ for magnifying glass used with $u < f$}
$$
is still working just fine. The image is a erect, not inverted. In this case the image is a virtual image, but the formulae do not tell you that. (The concept of a virtual image is simply that it is a location where light appears to have come from if we pretend the light arrived at its final direction of travel just by travelling in a straight line, undeviated by any lens or mirror. Of course the light did not really do that but it is a useful way to describe the final outcome.)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are referring to lenses from the formula , yes your understanding is true;

But the formula for mirror has a negative sign in it whereas the magnification formula for lens has a positive sign in it.

Magnification $= V / U$ for lenses ,

Magnification $= -V/U$ for mirrors